# Docker and WordPress quickstart | No wp-content folder upon install

Tags: wordpress, docker

So I was following this [quickstart guide](https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/) on getting a WordPress instance up and running.

I went through all the steps, logged into the WordPress site on localhost, played around with some themes, but I noticed that in my local directory, I don't see any of the WordPress files or folders.

I only see the `docker-compose.yml` file that I created.

I also followed some other guides on YouTube, but the same thing kept happening.

Anyone ever face this issue? I assume I must be just doing some type of configuration wrong upon setup, but I am not sure what that could be.

Comment: Share your docker-compose-file please

Comment: @EncangCutbray The OP linked to the guide with the docker-compose file that was used.

Comment: yeah my docker-compose file looks exactly like it does inside that guide. Maybe that could be the issue? I was supposed to change some things up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wordpress files are stored inside a container that docker runs.

- Read more about containers here: https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container

In order to visit your files, you need to go into the container. You can do so by following these steps:

1. Get the container id using `docker ps`.

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
6e2c2fcab7c8        mailhog/mailhog     "MailHog"                5 hours ago         Up 5 hours          0.0.0.0:1025->1025/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8025->8025/tcp  srv-server_mailhog_1
```

2. Execute a bash session inside the container using `docker exec`.

> docker exec -it 6e2c2fcab7c8 /bin/bash

the `-it` flags are:

- (i) Keep STDIN open even if not attached
- (t) Allocate a pseudo-TTY

---

If you get this message:

> "exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Then use `/bin/sh` instead as all containers aren't build with bash, but shell instead.

Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Comment: Okay let me try this!

Comment: Ohhh okay, so i did get this going. I wonder then how other people got their files inside the same directory upon docker-compose.

Comment: @MrTNader that's called a volume, whereas a specified directory becomes the container data. See this docker-compose.yml for example: https://github.com/fossbarrow/clean-laravel-with-docker/blob/main/docker-compose.yml